# how to put for loop in between the expect script send and expect

Tags: linux, shell, tcl, expect

how to put for loop in between the expect script send and expect

```
/usr/bin/expect << EOF  

spawn ssh user@127.0.0.1  
expect "password:"  
send "test1"  
expect "hello#"  
for {set x 0} {$x<2} {incr x} {  
    send "test2"  
    expect "hello#"  
}  
send "test3"  
expect "hello#"  
EOF
```

Comment: Getting like below
missing operand at _@_
in expression "_@_<2"
    (parsing expression "<2")
    invoked from within
"for {set x 0} {<2} {incr x} {
        send "test2\r"
    expect "hello#>"
    }"

Comment: You are making things unnecessarilly complicated for yourself by using the here document. I suggest to get rid of that and run the script with expect instead of bash. Just change the top line to: #!/usr/bin/expect

Comment: If you insist on using a here document, change the first line to "/usr/bin/expect << 'EOF'" (single quotes around EOF). That way the $x will not be substituted by bash.

Comment: Embedding Expect code in shell scripts is kind of tricky and error-prone. You can try my [sexpect (Expect for Shells)](https://github.com/clarkwang/sexpect/).

Answer (score 2):

The problem is you've got bash and Tcl/Expect both thinking they should handle `$x` in that expression (or in general). This is a bad state of affairs, and highly prone to errors!

My recommendation is to not use here-documents for Expect scripts; it might be a common practice, but it is a bad one! Simplifying your code *slightly* to this will resolve your problem:

```
#!/usr/bin/expect

spawn ssh user@127.0.0.1  
expect "password:"  
send "test1"  
expect "hello#"  
for {set x 0} {$x<2} {incr x} {  
    send "test2"  
    expect "hello#"  
}  
send "test3"  
expect "hello#"
```

This is literally the contents of there heredoc with `#!/usr/bin/expect` at the top.

In my experience, almost all programs that involve multiple levels of substitution, in any language or combination of languages, are bug-prone unless extreme caution is taken; it's almost always better to write code to not require that. It's easier to write, and much easier to debug. The "downside" is that you might need to use several files, but that's what we have filesystems for. (Your case appears to be simple enough to not need that.)